# Why isn't 'flask' found when running python3 in a terminal?

Tags: python, flask

In my VSCode terminal, I try to do

```
python3 
from app import db
```

and I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

In my `app.py` I have

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL"] = "sqlite:///test.db" 
db = SQLAlchemy(app) # Initializes the database 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.integer, default=0)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self): # Returns a string when a new element is created
        return '<Tsk %r>' % self.id
```

I am using virtualenv, and I made sure it was activated both when I installed flask & when I tried to do this.

I am following this tutorial: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA&t=953s) tutorial, and at 20:01 he instructs us to do this. What is wrong here?

Comment: try to check if it there:  pip list or pip3 list

Comment: i tried, and Flask & Flask-SQLAlchemy along with others were returned. Is there supposed to be a 'flask' as well? (As in without a capitalized F)

Comment: are you in the same environment?

Comment: yes, both when installing flask & when trying to do import db from app in my terminal

Comment: What happens if you use `python3 -m pip list` instead of `pip list`? How about `pip3 list`? What happens if you use `python3` and then try `import sys` and `sys.executable` - does it show a path in your venv?

Comment: with python3 -m pip list, it doesn't return anything flask-related. With pip3 list, it returns the same as pip list. When I do sys.executable, it shows a path into Appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python3.exe. Which I guess isn't into my venv. What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError is thrown when a package/library is not found. Ensure that you have installed Flask in your virtual environment by running:

```
pip install flask
```

or `conda install flask` if you're using conda.

To check if the package is already installed, run:

```
pip list
```

Comment: flask is installed. however when I try to import 'db' from my app.py in the Terminal, it says it isn't. When I use pip list, "Flask" and "Flask-SQLAlchemy" are returned.